# Variable not accessing inside of function

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitch

ive made a function for my twitch bot. which when they input a command checks if they are already in the list. if they are not in the list it will add them to the list. The code below outputs this : `[ undefined ]`
`[17:53] info: [#kong_plays] *<kng_bot>: 1`

```
var wtpLength = [];
function lfg(user){
    WTPLength = viewersWTP.length;
    if (WTPLength !== 0) {
        viewersWTP = viewersWTP - 1
        while(WTPLength !== -1){
            if(user === viewersWTP[WTPLength]){
                console.log("Already in list")
                client.action("kong_plays",user+" you cannot execute this command again until kong pulls a viewer to play with him!")
            }else{
            viewersWTP.push(user['display-name'])
            console.log("Added into list")
            client.action("kong_plays",viewersWTP)
            }
        }
    }else{
        viewersWTP.push(user['display-name'])
            console.log(viewersWTP)
            client.action("kong_plays","1"+viewersWTP)
    }
}
```

Comment: `viewersWTP` in your code is not defined. Define it with `var viewersWTP = []` outside the function.

Comment: yeah but if the else gets triggered it should add something to the list

Comment: It adds nothing to the list because that variable is undefined. Define it outside your function.

Comment: what? i dont really understand show code maybe?

Comment: You have called viewersWTP in every statement and will always get an undefined error. You've also defined wtpLength but are using WTPLength. Javascript is case sensitive.

Comment: Put `var viewersWTP = [];` anywhere before your function.

Comment: Dont worry fixed `user['display-name']` => `user`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `user['display-name']` into `user`. You passed that var throught the function

Answer (score 0):

Something like this may work for you.  You are using variables that are undefined.  It also looks as though you are not paying attention to the cases of the variables that you are defining.

```
var viewersWTP = [];   // add this or define it elsewhere
function lfg(user){
    var wtpLength = viewersWTP.length;
    if (wtpLength !== 0) {
        viewersWTP = viewersWTP - 1
        while(wtpLength !== -1){
            if(user === viewersWTP[wtpLength]){
                console.log("Already in list")
                client.action("kong_plays",user+" you cannot execute this command again until kong pulls a viewer to play with him!")
            }else{
            viewersWTP.push(user['display-name'])
            console.log("Added into list")
            client.action("kong_plays",viewersWTP)
            }
        }
    }else{
        viewersWTP.push(user['display-name'])
            console.log(viewersWTP)
            client.action("kong_plays","1"+viewersWTP)
    }
}
```